# Angular Reactive Forms FormArray - cannot assign second FormGroup element

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I am fighting with Reactive Forms and nested FormArray.
I am in the process of developing app to show clients with multiple addresses.
FormArray supposed to hold multiple address and using *ngFor I would like to show them to the user.

Everything works, except I cannot add more them item to FormArray (Addresses)
Even if I have specified 2 elements in the array I still get only one assigned.

What is wrong with my code?

**address.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientsService } from '../../../shared/clients.service';
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-address',
  templateUrl: './address.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address.component.css']
})
export class AddressComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public clientService: ClientsService) { }

  get Addresses(): FormArray{
    return <FormArray>this.clientService.clientForm.get('Addresses');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

**clients.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClientsService {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) { }

  clientForm = this.buildClientData();

  initializeFormGroup() {   
    this.clientForm.patchValue({
      Id: 0,
      CompId: null,
      NIP: null,
      ClientRelation: '',
      CompanyName: '',
      BusinessType: '',
      UsName: '',
      Addresses: [{
        Id: 0,
        Type: 'Company',
        Country: '',
        Wojewodztwo: '',
        Powiat: '',
        Gmina: 'testo',
        City: '',
        StreetName: '',
        StreetNo: '',
        ApartmentNo: '',
        PostalCode: '',
        PostalCity: ''
      },
      {
        Id: 1,
        Type: 'Accomodation',
        Country: '',
        Wojewodztwo: '',
        Powiat: '',
        Gmina: 'testo',
        City: '',
        StreetName: '',
        StreetNo: '',
        ApartmentNo: '',
        PostalCode: '',
        PostalCity: ''
      },
    ],
      Phone: '',
      Active: false,
      Debtor: false,
      Poa: '',
      PoaPayment: ''
    });
    
    console.log(this.clientForm);
  }

  buildClientData(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group ({    
      Id: 0,
      CompId: null,
      NIP: null,
      ClientRelation: '',
      CompanyName: '',
      BusinessType: '',
      UsName: '',
      Addresses: this.fb.array([this.buildClientAddress()]),
      Phone: '',
      Active: false,
      Debtor: false,
      Poa: '',
      PoaPayment: ''
    });
  }

  buildClientAddress(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      Id: null,
      Type: '',
      Country: '',
      Wojewodztwo: '',
      Powiat: '',
      Gmina: '',
      City: '',
      StreetName: '',
      StreetNo: '',
      ApartmentNo: '',
      PostalCode: '',
      PostalCity: ''
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You were added one object to the formgroup of  buildClientAddress. If you add two set of  object, you will get another one.

Comment: @Muthupriya, wow, you are correct. This one was a test to check if it works. What if I have dynamically chaning number of addresses?

Comment: @Muthupriya, you should post it as an anwser so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were added one object to the formgroup of buildClientAddress. If you add two set of object, you will get another one.

If you want this as dynamically, you have to provide some button in front end, so that you will provide your logic under that button action.

```
addItem(): void {
  this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  this.items.push(this.createItem());
}

createItem(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    name: '',
    description: '',
    price: ''
  });
}
```